# each dentro de un array

Tags: jquery, calendar

Tengo el siguiente código y necesito poder agregar los eventos desde un bucle que es generado con la data que retorna el ajax y lo hago de la siguiente manera, pero no me lo permite, intente crear el array fuera y pasarle la variable pero el new se interpreta antes de tiempo generando error ya que events espera tal cual el siguiente el formato alli comentado dentro de events

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'result3.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {ias8d4as8d: 'sfsdfdsf'},
    success: function(data){

        resultado=data;
        //console.log(JSON.parse(resultado));
        var jsonArr = [];

        // plugin defaults
        $.fn.eCalendar.defaults = {
            weekDays: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab'],
            months: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            textArrows: {previous: '<', next: '>'},
            eventTitle: 'Eventos',
            url: '',
            events: [
                //{title: 'Event Title 1rr', description: 'Description 1', datetime: new Date(2019, 4, 12, 17)}
                    $(jQuery.parseJSON(data)).each(function() {
                        jsonArr.push({
                            title: this.title,
                            description: this.title,
                            datetime: new Date(2019, 4, 12, 17)
                        })
                    })
            ],
            firstDayOfWeek: 0
        };

    },
    async: false
});
```